# Missing recipe name and method

Tags: chocolate, coffee, pudding

I have a list of ingredients but no recipe name or method - does anyone know what it may be?

The ingredients are:

- 200ml strong coffee
- 1 Tabs Demerara sugar
- 75g plain chocolate

Also listed separately:

- 100g white chocolate
- 4 eggs separated
- 75g caster sugar
- 500g mascarpone cheese

I guess you must have to mix the two lots together and then combine but I'm just not sure how and what it makes!  Sounds good though.

Comment: I did wonder this but as you observed no sponge fingers list or cocoa powder.  Just reading through again I'm wondering if it could even be for a cheesecake - but then no biscuit base mentioned.

Comment: Hi Lyco, here on Stack Exchange, you can comment on each post separately - this seems to go to my answer, not to your question. Anyway, I'll answer here. You can surely fill a no-bake cheesecake with whatever you like, but then you have no use for the moccha. You cannot mix them together, because it will get way too liquid. Also, mascarpone is not that common in cheesecakes and it is the traditional main ingredient in tiramisu. The combination of mascarpone-based cream and the coffee based liquid is quite distinctive.

Comment: I presume the demerara is a tablespooon (Tbs) and that "Tabs" is a typo.  But the sugar content of plain chocolate varies by much more than this (anywhere from 40% to >90%) so the added sugar in part 1 is almost irrelevant to the overall flavour. That makes me suspicious of further transcription errors.

Comment: Absent the cake portion, the ingredients are precisely as listed for the [Waitrose white and dark chocolate tiramisu](http://www.waitrose.com/home/recipes/recipe_directory/w/white_and_dark_chocolate_tiramisu.html)

Comment: I think @Dorothy has got it. Maybe someone was modifying the recipe to use ready-made cake so omitted the middle section. (I've seen recipes using madeira cake for example)

Comment: @ChrisH since we don't do recipes, shall I just leave it as a comment with the link?

Comment: @Dorothy, I'd answer if I were you. While we don't do recipe requests, if the answer turns out to be a recipe it deserves to be accepted (and voted up)

Comment: Dorothy has the answer. This isn't a list of ingredients, it's two separate lists of ingredients for two parts of a three-part recipe.

Answer (score 11):

Absent the cake portion, the ingredients are precisely as listed for the [Waitrose White and Dark Chocolate Tiramisu](http://www.waitrose.com/home/recipes/recipe_directory/w/white_and_dark_chocolate_tiramisu.html). Recipe and image courtesy of Waitrose.com

As @ChrisH has suggested, someone may have been modifying the recipe to use ready-made cake, such as a Madeira.

[image: Image courtesy of Waitrose.com]

> *Coffee chocolate syrup*
>   200ml strong coffee
>   1 tbsp demerara sugar
>   75g plain chocolate, finely chopped
>
> *Cake*
>   125g unsalted butter, softened, plus extra for greasing
>   225g caster sugar
>   2 large eggs, lightly beaten
>   1 tsp vanilla extract
>   75g plain chocolate, melted
>   175g essential Waitrose plain flour
>   25g cocoa powder
>   1 tsp bicarbonate of soda
>   200ml essential Waitrose soured cream
>
> *Mascarpone and chocolate cream*
>   100g white chocolate, chopped
>   4 large eggs, separated
>   75g caster sugar
>   500g mascarpone

And, in the interest of not presenting a full recipe, here is my abridged version of the directions; follow the link for the full details.

> Prepare the cake layers the day before you plan to assemble the tiramisu.
>
> The next day, prepare the coffee syrup. Pour the hot coffee into a bowl, add the sugar and chopped chocolate and stir until smooth and the chocolate has completely melted.
>
> Prepare the mascarpone cream. Melt the white chocolate in a bowl over a pan of simmering water. Stir until smooth, then set aside to cool slightly. In a bowl, whisk the egg yolks and caster sugar until the mixture has doubled in volume and leaves a ribbon trail when the whisk is lifted. Add the mascarpone and melted white chocolate and whisk again until smooth. In another bowl, whisk the egg whites with a pinch of salt until they hold a stiff peak. Fold the egg whites into the mascarpone mixture using a large metal spoon.
>
> To assemble the tiramisu, spoon a layer of the mascarpone cream into the bottom of each of glass and top with a layer of cake. Drizzle liberally with the coffee syrup. Add another layer of the cream, cake, syrup and a final layer of cream. Serve chilled, perhaps scattered with white and dark chocolate shavings.

Answer (score 4):

Mixing them together would give you a sauce (if incorporated properly first). It could be an interesting new thing if you need it, but I can't imagine that many places to use it.

For me, this is clearly intended as a Tiramisu recipe, slightly non-traditional. Somebody left out the lady fingers. You mix the first ingredients to make moccha, then pour it over the lady fingers.

For the cream, there are two possibilities. One is to use all ingredients. Beat the yolks with the sugar to ribbons, add the mascarpone, then slowly add the just-melted chocolate. Fold in the eggwhites beaten to soft peaks. Put over the ladyfingers, and when hardened in the fridge, sift cocoa powder over it.

While this is more likely, I don't see cocoa powder in the ingredients either. Also, so much cocoa might be so strong as to dominate the subtle taste of white chocolate. So you could make the same cream, leaving out the melted chocolate. Then, when the tiramisu has set, cover with grated white chocolate. This is also easier to make, if you are not experienced making creams and working with melted chocolate.

**Update** I made the recipe yesterday, now it has set after a night in the fridge. I put 90 g of the cream in an ice cream cup, and poured 30 g of the coffee mixture on it. Then I layered the rest as a normal mascarpone, using storebought lady fingers.

The version in the bowl could have used improvement. Some of the liquid found a way to flow to the bottom of the cup. The rest of it stayed on top, where it made a not-so-appetizing surface, slightly seeping into the cream. It did harden in the end, but it is not something a master pattisier would have made. If you insist on using it this way, you should do something else. For example, you could make a ganache by using 200 g of chocolate and 75 g of coffee, instead of the other way round. You can throw in a bit of instant coffee if you want a stronger taste.

The tiramisu looks like a standard tiramisu. It layered well, the amount of liquid was just enough to soak two layers of ladyfingers. All in all, it seems like a good recipe. I have not eaten it yet, but I am certain it will taste delicious. [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it could be a variation of this recipe for White Chocolate Mascarpone Cream from  [Great British Chefs](http://www.greatbritishchefs.com/recipes/white-chocolate-mascarpone-cream-recipe) :

[image]

> 50g of white chocolate, (I used Godiva white chocolate pearls)
>
> 2 eggs, yolks and white separated
>
> 100g of caster sugar
>
> 1 vanilla pod
>
> 250g of mascarpone cream cheese
>
> 150g of dark chocolate, (I used Godiva dark chocolate pearls)
>
> 1. Melt the white chocolate in a bain-marie then set aside to cool slightly. Beat the egg yolks together with the caster sugar and the scraped seeds from the vanilla pod for a few minutes until pale and creamy
> 2. Add in the mascarpone cheese and then pour in the cooled melted white chocolate. Stir until smooth and well combined
> 3. In a separate, very clean bowl, whisk the egg whites until stiff. Fold the egg whites into the mascarpone and egg mixture and spoon into serving glasses; four or six, depending on indulgence levels. Chill for at least 1 hour
> 4. Just before serving melt the dark chocolate in a bain-marie and drizzle a little over each dessert and serve immediately

I'm thinking that that the coffee and sugar would be mixed with the melted dark chocolate for the last step of the recipe.

EDIT: You would probably need to halve the coffee, sugar, and dark chocolate if you were to use the amounts in this recipe for the cream portion. It may be up to some experimenting to get the final result to your liking.

Comment: good guess, but look at the amounts. If you pour almost 300 g of coffee over not quite 900 g of cream, you won't have a cream with a few streaks of chocolate on top, you will have a portion of moccha sloshing above a portion of cream, slowly dissolving into a soup.

Comment: @rumtscho His ingredient amount would make roughly twice as much of the cream portion as this recipe does. I should have noted that he would need to halve that part of the recipe.

Comment: I was calculating with his numbers, not yours. 500 g mascarpone + 200 g eggs + 100 g chocolate + 75 g sugar is 875 g cream. 200 ml coffee + 75 g chocolate + a bit of sugar is about 300 g liquid. Imagine filling that glass in the picture to 3/4 and pouring slightly thickened coffee over it until it is ifull. The only thing that will work is if you add gelatine or a similar thickener, but it is much weirder that this would be missing, instead of having the lady fingers of tiramisu missing.

Comment: @rumtscho Yes, you were. Missed that. And I don't disagree with your idea. However, the way the ingredients are broken up suggests to me that it may be some variation of this cream dessert. As we don't know what the recipe is for, any answer is a guess.